How can I implement third-party raster tiles to a map from Mapbox in my Android Studio project?
I’m working on a project in Android Studio where I’m using Mapbox. I’m interested in implementing the seamarks from OpenSeaMap in my project. Here’s my attempt:
fun onMapReady(style: String, cameraOptions: CameraOptions) {
with(mapView) {
    mapView.mapboxMap.setCamera(cameraOptions)

    mapboxMap.addOnMoveListener(
        object : OnMoveListener {
            override fun onMoveBegin(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {

            }

            override fun onMove(detector: MoveGestureDetector): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onMoveEnd(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
                annotationRepository.clearViewAnnoations()
            }
        }
    )

    mapboxMap.loadStyle(style) {

        try {
            val rasterSource = RasterSource.Builder("openseamap-source")
                .url("https://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
                .tileSize(256)
                .build()

            it.addSource(rasterSource)

            val rasterLayer = RasterLayer("openseamap-layer", "openseamap-source")
            it.addLayerAbove(rasterLayer, "water")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Mapbox", "Error adding source or layer: ${e.message}")
        }


    }


}

}
When I run the app, the seamarks are not displayed. I don’t get an error message in my logcat either.
I’ve tried looking at projects and tutorials online, but that hasn’t helped. The approach I see elsewhere is pretty much the same as mine (only they use HTML and not Kotlin).
